# Question from Folland Chapter 1 Exercise 14

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem is the following:

> If $\mu$ is a semifinite measure and $\mu(E)=\infty$, for any $C>0$ there exists $F \subset E$ with $C < \mu(F) < \infty$.

We were told as a hint to consider the set $F = \left\lbrace F\subset E : 0 < \mu(F)<\infty \right\rbrace$. I know that because $\mu$ is semifinite, we must have that $F$ is nonempty by definition (and that's pretty much all $\mu$ being semifinite tells me). However, I don't see any reason why for any $C>0$ I can find an element in this set that satisfies the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Say $\alpha$ is the supremum of $\mu(F)$ over all $F\subset E$ with $\mu(F)<\infty$. If $\alpha=\infty$ you're done.

Suppose $\alpha<\infty$. Then $\alpha-1/n<\alpha$, so for every $n$ there exists $F_n\subset E$ with $\alpha-1/n<\mu(F_n)<\infty$. Let $S_n=\bigcup_{j=1}^n F_j$. Then $\mu(S_n)>\alpha-1/n$. Also $S_n\subset E$ and $\mu(S_n)<\infty$, so the definition of $\alpha$ shows that $\mu(S_n)\le\alpha$.

Now let $S=\bigcup S_n$. Since the $S_n$ are increasing, the inequalities in the previous paragraph show that $\mu(S)=\alpha$.

So let $E'=E\setminus S$. Then $\mu(E')=\infty$. So there exists $A\subset E'$ with $0<\mu(A)<\infty$.

So $S\cup A\subset E$ and $\alpha < \mu(S\cup A)<\infty$, contradicting the definition of $\alpha$.

Comment: Why is it that we're done if $\alpha = \infty$? I don't understand  why that implies the result

Comment: Running out of letters.... say $M=\{\mu(F)\,:\,F\subset E,0<\mu(F)<\infty\}$. So $\alpha=\sup(M)$. Exactly what does it _mean_ to say the supremum of a set of real numbers is $\infty$?

Comment: Hint: The supremum of a set is the least upper bound. So a number less than the supremum is not an upper bound...

Comment: If the sup of a set of real numbers is $\infty$, then there's no real upper bound of the set, right?

Comment: Right. So $C$ is not an upper bound...

Comment: Ah ok I think I'm starting to see it. I think I was confused as I was trying to think of $C$ as a lower bound

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, in the case $\alpha<\infty$, we know $S_n\in M$ for all finite n, so $\mu(S_n)\le \alpha$. But, how do you know $\mu(S)<\infty$, so $S\in M$, so $\mu(S)=\alpha$

Comment: @khashayar The $S_n$ are increasing (that is, $S_n\subset S_{n+1}$.)